# including stdio when calling WriteConsole results in error

Tags: c++, winapi, console, mingw

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char s[] = "Hello\n";
  HANDLE stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  unsigned long cChars;
  WriteConsole(stdout, s, lstrlen(s), &cChars, NULL);
}
```

result: `error: declaration of '_iob' as array of references`

but when I comment out `stdio.h`, it compiles ok. What's wrong here ?

Compiler is MinGW.

Comment: Does it give a line number of file name along with the error? Does changing the order of the #include's change anything?

Comment: Yes, error points to stdout, and that was the problem, it is reserved name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the platform, stdout is probably a macro, so better not use that name. Replace

```
HANDLE stdout = ...
```

with

```
HANDLE out = ...
```

and then

```
WriteConsole(out, ...
```

stdout is defined in stdio.h, that's why it fails only when this file is included. But to be safe, never use that name for any self-defined variable.

Comment: +1 The header file has this: `#define stdout  (&_iob[STDOUT_FILENO])`

Comment: It's not "depending on the platform". *The standard* says it's a macro.

Answer (score 1):

the stdout is already defined by system.. try changing it to _stdout or something else